# May I switch 205/70/16 with 205/60/16 tires?

Tags: tires

May I substitute 205/60/16 snow tires for 205/70/16 tires?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a helpful resource:

[Tire Size Calculator](https://tiresize.com/calculator/)

Comparing your two:

[image: Comparison]

So you can see that the 60 profile snow tire is "shorter" than the 70 you have on it now.  Chances are good that it will fit as the thing you need to concern yourself about the most is clearance between the tire and the car itself.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I realized I had written backwards as far as the exchange was going ... misread what the OP stated. Glad you got it right :o)

Comment: @RML note that in UK it is illegal for the speedometer to under-read your actual speed. Over-read by up to 10%: OK. Under-read at all: BAD. Manufacturers typically calibrate midway at over-read by 5% to give them leeway in compliance.

Comment: @WeatherVane - I think that's fairly regular. I mean, if it's reading more miles then the vehicle has gone, the warranty goes away faster ...

Comment: Downsizing this much in overall diameter is a pretty serious deal, especially in newer cars with all the electronic traction control, ABS, AWD ... This could really screw up some stuff, depending on the vehicle. I would strongly recommend against it, without knowing what vehicle we are talking about here. That's almost 2 inches, and the car's various systems might interpret the differences in sensor feed back as false conditions.